# XML Parser: Why do I get my data in a loop?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Hope anyone can help me... I want to import records from an xml file into a sql database. The first record is saved correctly, the second is filled with the data of two records, the third with the data of three records and so on...
What have I done wrong? I´m a noob, please consider that in your reply.
Because I really don´t know where to find the problem exactly, I have to show the whole php-code. I really need your help - thanks in advance!!

This is my php-file:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

/**
* Parser Class
*/
class Parser
{
var $dbo;
var $partner;

function __construct($dbo, $parser, $id) {
    $this->dbo = $dbo;
    $this->partner = new stdClass();
    $this->partner->name = $parser;
    $this->partner->id = $id;
}

function go() {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // creating parser object
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');

    // set encoding to UTF-8
    xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,
            XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING,
            'UTF-8');

    // initializing the handler class
    $handler = new XMLHandlerClass(
            $this->dbo,
            $this->partner);

    // setting up the handlers
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser,
            array($handler, 'startElement'),
            array($handler, 'endElement'));
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser,
            array($handler, 'contents'));

    // path to the xml file
    $file = JPATH_SITE.DS.'tmp'.DS.'routes.xml';

    // open the file to read
    if (!($fp = fopen($file, "r"))) {
        die('konnte xml nicht öffnen');
        return false;
    }

    // read line after line from the xml file
    $data = null;
    while ($data = fgets($fp, 100000)) {
        if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
            die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
                xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),
                xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
        }
    }

    // free the xml parser
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

    // every thing fine?
    return true;
}
}

/**
* XML Handler Class
*/
class XMLHandlerClass
{
var $dbo;
var $partner;

var $element;

var $saveCounter = 0;
var $clearCounter = 0;

var $cabintype;
var $counterPrice = 0;

var $counterRoute = 0;

var $item;

var $api;

function __construct($dbo, $partner) {

    // save params
    $this->dbo = $dbo;
    $this->partner = $partner;

    // include api
    include_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR
            .DS.'api'.DS.'KreuzfahrtenAPI.php';

    // initialize api
    $this->api = new KreuzfahrtenAPI($this->dbo,
            $this->partner->name,
            $this->partner->id);
}

function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs) {
    // don't give up
    set_time_limit(120);

    // get the name
    $this->element = strtolower($name);

    // bevor das speichern der tripps beginnt,
    // aber eigentlich schon die routen informationen da sind
    // soll die dauer noch um 1 gekürzt werden
    if ($this->element == "listoftrips") {
        $this->item['dauer'] -= 1;
    }
}

function endElement($parser, $name) {

    // don't give up
    set_time_limit(120);

    // get the name
    $name = strtolower($name);

    // counter hochzählen
    switch ($name) {
        case "port":
            $this->counterRoute++;
            break;
        case "cabin":
            $this->counterPrice++;
            break;
        case "trip":
            $this->saveCounter++;
            $this->save();
            break;
        case "route":
            $this->clearCounter++;
            $this->clear();
            break;
    }
}

function contents($parser, $data) {

    // remove quots
    $data = $this->reEn($data);

    // assign the $data by the $this->element
    switch ($this->element) {
        case "routeid":
            $this->item['routeid'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "name":
            $this->item['titel'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "duration":
            $this->item['dauer'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "port":
            if ($this->counterRoute != 0 && $this->counterRoute != 1) {
                $this->item['route'][$this->counterRoute-2] .= $data;
            }
            break;
        case "priceoverview":
            if ($data == "Einzel") break;
            switch ($data) {
                case "bestinsidecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Innenkabine";
                    break;
                case "bestoutsidecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Außenkabine";
                    break;
                case "bestsuitecabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Suite";
                    break;
                case "bestbalconycabinprice":
                    $this->cabintype = "Balkonkabine";
                    break;
                default:
                    die('Kein passender Kabinentyp '.$data);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "bestprice":
            $cabinetype = $this->cabintype;
            $this->item['prices'][$cabinetype][$this->counterPrice] .= 
            str_replace(',', '.', $data);
            unset($cabinetype);
            break;
        case "tripbegins":
            $this->item['beginn'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "tripends":
            $this->item['ende'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "destinationname":
            $this->item['zielgebiet'] .= $data;
            break;
        case "shipname":
            $this->item['schiff'] .= $data;
            break;
    }
}

function reEn($subject) {
    $toDel = array (
        '"',
        "'"
    );
    $toRe = array(
        '',
        ''
    );
    $subject = str_replace($toDel, $toRe, $subject);
    return $subject;
}

function clear($error = false) {
    if ($error) {
        $title = "ERROR:Clear";
        $description = "ITEM:\n"
            .$this->api->implodeItem($this->item);
        $this->api->setErrorMsg($title,$description);
    }

    $this->element = null;
    $this->item = null;
    $this->cabintype = null;
    $this->counterPrice = 0;
    $this->counterRoute = 0;
}

function save() {
    // neues zeitlimit setzen
    set_time_limit(120);

    // prüfe ob alle daten vorhanden sind
    if (empty($this->item['titel'])
            || empty($this->item['routeid'])
            || empty($this->item['dauer'])
            || !is_array($this->item['route'])
            || !is_array($this->item['prices'])
            || empty($this->item['beginn'])
            || empty($this->item['ende'])
            || empty($this->item['zielgebiet'])
            || empty($this->item['schiff'])
                    ) {
        $this->clear(TRUE);
        return false;
    } else {
        // daten für api vorbereichten

        // -- url
        $this->item['url'] = "www.domain.com/?fuseaction=product.showroute="
                .$this->item['routeid']
                ."&ID=112201000000";
        // -- datum
        $this->item['beginn'] = $this->api->convertDate(
                explode('.', $this->item['beginn'])
        );
        $this->item['ende'] = $this->api->convertDate(
                explode('.', $this->item['ende'])
        );
        // reise mit der api speichern
        $this->api->save($this->item);

        // nicht mehr nötige daten löschen
        unset($this->item['beginn'],
                $this->item['ende'],
                $this->item['prices']);
    }
}
}
?>
```

These are my errors - there is data from different xml-records in each element... And I don´t know why - I get desperate...

```
1st record:
zielgebiet = Alaska
routeid = 24118
titel = Farben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New York

2nd record:
zielgebiet = AlaskaNeuengland
routeid = 2411824121
titel = Farben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New YorkFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New York

3rd record:
zielgebiet = AlaskaNeuenglandNordamerika
routeid = 241182412124142
titel = Farben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New YorkFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New YorkFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab Québec

4th record:
zielgebiet = AlaskaNeuenglandNordamerikaNew England
routeid = 24118241212414224206
titel = Farben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New YorkFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab New YorkFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab QuébecFarben von Kanada und Neuengland - ab Québec
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write data from XML into sql database only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110222/how-to-write-data-from-xml-into-sql-database-only-once)

Comment: Never ever duplicate your own questions. Instead make edit them to improve them. Also please concentrate on isolated programming questions, Stackoverflow is not an issue- or bug-tracker for your *own* code. Thank you for taking care!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have string concatenation occuring in multiple places, which will just append the string to each other, over and over for every time in the loop.

So Instead of.... `$this->item['titel'] .= $data;`

You just want...  `$this->item['titel'] = $data;`

So the EDITS to make are below...
Change this block to this....

```
switch ($this->element) {
    case "routeid":
        $this->item['routeid'] = $data;
        break;
    case "name":
        $this->item['titel'] = $data;
        break;
    case "duration":
        $this->item['dauer'] = $data;
        break;
    case "port":
        if ($this->counterRoute != 0 && $this->counterRoute != 1) {
            $this->item['route'][$this->counterRoute-2] = $data;
        }
```

And this block, to this....

```
case "bestprice":
        $cabinetype = $this->cabintype;
        $this->item['prices'][$cabinetype][$this->counterPrice] = 
        str_replace(',', '.', $data);
        unset($cabinetype);
        break;
    case "tripbegins":
        $this->item['beginn'] = $data;
        break;
    case "tripends":
        $this->item['ende'] = $data;
        break;
    case "destinationname":
        $this->item['zielgebiet'] = $data;
        break;
    case "shipname":
        $this->item['schiff'] = $data;
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the most problems. There is some problem left at case "port"... some of the entries are still filled with too much data... and I really don´t know why...

Comment: Please take care that such answers could be interpreted as feeding Help Vampires which is discouraged on this website. Check a users history, probably direct her/him back to the previous question to not answer duplicate questions that tend into the "too localized" area.

Answer (score 0):

What if you, instead of this:

```
$this->item['routeid'] .= $data;
```

Just use this:

```
$this->item['routeid'] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the cause, at least judging by the comment above the code block:

```
// assign the $data by the $this->element
switch ($this->element) {
    case "routeid":
        $this->item['routeid'] .= $data;
        break;
    // etc.
```

When you use:

```
$this->item['routeid'] .= $data;
                       ^ here
```

you are concatenating `$data` to the current content of `$this->item['routeid']`.

You probably just want:

```
$this->item['routeid'] = $data;
```

Note that this occurs in multiple places.